# Angular Generate PDF from a Component Dynamic. without openening every single Data entry

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pdf, npm

My Problem is i want to convert a lot of Data (Measurement Data) exported to a pdf. So it shows it in the Angular app but i want to export the bunch of Data into a pdf without opening every single measurement data and export it by hand. It should also take the component Design into the PDF. is out there such a tool or have anyone an idea how i could handle it?

I have Tried

1. to export by a convert to PDF by hand
2. to generate the PDF with the PDF MAKER => https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfmake
3. to generate dynamic via the Backend generator.